# Two instances of application connected to same, altered database

Tags: database, relational-database, distributed-system

, Hello,

couple days ago at interview i was asked a strange(for me) question:

Imagine that you have 2 nodes with 1 instance of application in java per each. Each of that instances use same relational database - at node 3.  Now you need to make update for that database with new schema but you need to upgrade only 1 node.

So you have 1 instances of old application with old database config and 1 instances of new application with new database config running at same time with connection to same database.

And after some time if update is working fine old instance will be updated to new versions.

I told them that i don't know how to do that - as for i know it's impossible to run two versions of application that use different versions of database (some change was made to columns can't remember exactly).

Now after couple of days i still cannot find answer to that question. I have googled for answer but i have found nothing.

Could you please tell me if that's possible and give me some keywords to look for or links to tutorials or articles ?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't make changes that break things. (You already know this part.)

Adding a new, nullable column shouldn't break old code. Adding a new, nonnullable column *will* break old code. But use one or more triggers to manage the default value, and old code will keep working. These kinds of triggers are usually deprecated and dropped later.

Dropping a column will break old and new code. So deprecate the column, change the code to stop using the column, then drop it.

The underlying principles are simple. (But `simple != easy`.) There's more than one way to do this, and details vary.

- If you don't know for certain that a change won't break things, treat
  it like a breaking change.
- Identify the things that have to appear unchanged for the old code.
- Alter the database to keep working those things you just identified.
  That might involve adding triggers, updatable views, stored
  procedures, and so on.
- Write this stuff down. You're going to use it a lot.
- Update the code.
- Deprecate and remove the things you created to keep things working.

You ought to be able to catch these kinds of issues in your test environment. ("All of us have a test environment. Some of us are lucky enough to have a separate production environment." -- Unknown)